# Organising results from JSON file using Python lists?

Tags: python, json, list, set

I've parsed a JSON file containing Track Names and Album Names of about 3000 songs, and was getting nowhere with trying to organise it into a list of lists or something similar?

I essentially want to sort the items into a list of unique albums, each containing a list of tracks, and was wondering if this was actually possible, as I'm don't know how to assigned names to lists?

My code so far is as follows:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('.../playlist.json', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for playlist in data['playlists']:
    if playlist['name'] == 'PLAYLIST3':
        for item in playlist['items']:
            track = item['track']['trackName']
            album = item['track']['albumName']
```

Also, the songs aren't sorted in any particular manner.

**EDIT**:
This is what I did, which seemed to work fine in creating a list of dictionaries with a list of songs as the value and the album name as the key:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('C:/Users/nambi/Desktop/parse/playlist.json', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

listOfAlbums = {}

for playlist in data['playlists']:
    if playlist['name'] == 'P4':
        for item in playlist['items']:
            title = item['track']['trackName']
            album = item['track']['albumName']

            if album in listOfAlbums:
                listOfAlbums[album].append(title)
            else:
                listOfAlbums[album] = [title]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use collections.defaultdict as it allows to set the type of the value of each key.
In you case the key would be the album name and the value would be a list of tracks.

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

with open('.../playlist.json', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

result = defaultdict(list)
for playlist in data['playlists']:
    if playlist['name'] != 'PLAYLIST3':
        continue

    for item in playlist['items']:
        track = item['track']['trackName']
        album = item['track']['albumName']
        result[album].append(track)
```

**EDIT**: Additional improvements:

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import ifilter
from pprint import pprint

with open('.../playlist.json', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

result = defaultdict(list)
for playlist in ifilter(lambda p: p['name'] == 'PLAYLIST3', data['playlists']):
    for item in playlist['items']:
        track = item['track']['trackName']
        album = item['track']['albumName']
        result[album].append(track)
```

Comment: How would I print the results? Attempting to do so just prints stuff like `defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {})`

Comment: yeah it's fine, otherwise you can convert it to a dict and then print, or use pprint or dump to a json file ...

Comment: defaultdict is made exactly to solve your issue, as you don't need to check if the key exists or create it and set it as a list and then only you can append to it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to sort songs into unique albums which contain the list of their songs the code below should do the work.
The result is a `dict` to song `list`; if the track is not album it ignores it and if the album doesn't exist in `res` it creates it.

```
results = {}
for playlist in data['playlists']:
    # if playlist['name'] == 'PLAYLIST3':
    if 'items' in playlist:
        for item in playlist['items']:
            # extract data 
            track_name = item['track']['trackName']
            album = item['track']['albumName']
            # create album in results if not exist
            # if the album names are not following the same typo, normalize them here 
            # like album = album.lower()
            if album not in results:
                results[album] = []
            # if track is not once inserted in album insert it
            if track_name not in results[album]:
                results[album].append(track_name)
# use results as you wish
print(results)
```

Comment: I did something similar to this:

sorry don't know how to post code in the comments?

Comment: You could edit the question and share your final solution at the end, for future reference.